# Excel VBA: Insert row into table and fill down everything from row above

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with a little bit of VBA code I pulled together and I just can't find an answer somewhere else.
I have a table named TableOPQuery which has over 40 columns and over 10k rows.

There is a column called SPLITS where the user will write a value x (integer). If that value is greater than 1 then a row will be inserted under the row where the user wrote the value, because the purpose of that value is to add rows and copy everything the original row had (values, formulas, format) to make the same amount of rows specificied by the user including the original one, so it woul be like "x - 1".

Here is an example, because I propably couldn't explain it good enough:

```
Order   Provider       Amount   Type    Splits  Shipped
23     Shady company    10000   Whole   1   
30     That company     2000    Split   2   
*30     That company     2000   Split*
35     This company     420     Whole
```

So, you see, in row 1 (order 23), the user wrote 1, so no rows will be inserted. But, in  row 2 (order 30), the user wrote 2. So one more row will be inserted, copying everything from the row above (the one where the user inserted 2), to make 2 rows identical to each other.

I managed to piece toger this code that helps me in inserting whatever amount of rows the user wants, but for some reason I can not make it fill down from the original row where the user wrote the value and I want it to clear the contents in the SPLIT row to not trigger the code again.

I am stumped now, because the normal filldown fuction doesn't work. I can insert rows, **but I cant copy and fill down everything the row above has**, and I can't clear the column SPLITS either.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    Dim KeyCells As range
    Dim xValue As Integer
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tRows As Long
    Dim tCols As Long
    Dim originCell As String

    'I call a fuction that will give me the position of the column that has SPLITS in it, searching a predefined row (5:5). I know this is unnecessary but this is the best I could do because the column SPLITS might change of position (add/delete columns)
    col = ColumnNumberByHeader("Splits")

   'I use this to get the amount of rows the table has mostly
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableOPQuery")
    With tbl.DataBodyRange
        tRows = .Rows.Count
        tCols = .Columns.Count
    End With

   'An If to get a range using the a predefined start row (5), the col I got earlier, and the amount of rows the table has. If I get 0 as col is because the column does not exist
    If col <> 0 Then
        Set KeyCells = range(Cells(5, col), Cells(tRows, col))
    Else
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Check that column SPLITS exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Here is where the level noob magic happens. Rows start getting inserted if a value in the range I got in KeyCells happens
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        'If the value is not numeric then nothing will run
        If IsNumeric(Target) Then
            'If the target is greater than 1 then the amount of Target.Value minus 1 of rows will be inserted under the row where the change occurred
            If Target.Value > 1 Then 
                originCell = Target.Address       
                xValue = Target.Value - 1
                MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
                'A loop to insert the rows, I use - 4 because the Target.Address is of the whole worksheet, and not the table itself.
                For i = 1 To Target.Value - 1 Step 1
                    tbl.ListRows.Add (range(Target.Address).row - 4)
                    'Filling down into the inserted rows from the row of the originCell (where the user inserted the value)
                    range(originCell).EntireRow.FillDown
                Next i
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can I suggest allowing the user to fill everything out, and then use a macro (or button) to then do your steps you need? It seems a lot easier to read when there's less data, as your filling it out the goal you're looking to accomplish seems a little annoying when I'd be filling it.

Comment: So you mean to let users do their work and then have them press a button to do what I want to do? It is a great suggestion, actually. Thanks for the input, if that is what you meant. If not, please elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

### Assumption

- Sheet name (that contains the table): `Sheet1`
- Table Name: `TableOPQuery`
- Corresponding column header: `Splits`

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim tbl As ListObject
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim SCI As Integer 'Specific Column Index
        Dim CN As String 'Column Name

        CN = "Splits"
        Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("TableOPQuery")
        Set rng = Range("TableOPQuery[#All]")
        SCI = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CN, Range("TableOPQuery[#Headers]"), 0)

        If Cells(rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Column + SCI - 1) > 1 Then
            tbl.ListRows.Add
            Range(Cells(rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count, rng.Column).Address & ":" & _
                Cells(rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count, rng.Column + rng.Columns.Count - 1).Address).FillDown
        End If

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the work! I can't try it out right now but I will soon and I will let you know about it.